# Codewars exercise "Count by X" not working

Tags: ruby

I'm tryng to do this exercise:

> Create a function with two arguments that will return a list of length
>   (n) with multiples of (x).
>
> Assume both the given number and the number of times to count will be
>   positive numbers greater than 0.
>
> Return the results as an array (or list in Python, Haskell or Elixir).
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> count_by(1,10) #should return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
> count_by(2,5) #should return [2,4,6,8,10]
> ```

Quite easy, nothing to say. BUT I really do not understand why my code is not working. 
PLease DO NOT GIVE ME NEW CODE OR SOLUTION, I JUST WANT TO UNDERSTAND WHY MINE DOESN'T WORK.

My solution:

```
def count_by(x, n)
  arrays = []
  arrays.push(x)
  valore_x = x

  unless arrays.count == n
    arrays.push( x + valore_x)
    x += valore_x
  end

  return arrays
end

count_by(3, 5)
```

ERROR MESSAGE =

```
Expected: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], instead got: [1, 2]
✘ Expected: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], instead got: [2, 4]
✘ Expected: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15], instead got: [3, 6]
✘ Expected: [50, 100, 150, 200, 250], instead got: [50, 100]
✘ Expected: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500], instead got: [100, 200].
```

So looks like that my code do not put all the numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
unless arrays.count == n
```

to

```
until arrays.count == n
```

`unless` is not a loop. It's just like an if, but the code is executed if the condition is false.
`until` is just like `while`, but the code is executed while the condition is false.

Comment: What a shame, I have just confused until and unless. thanks >.>.

Comment: I imagined. My pleasure Sir :)

Comment: _"..executed until the condition is false"_ should it say _"until the condition is true"_?

Answer (score 2):

Now you have answer on your question, so I just recommend one more variant of solution, I think it's more ruby-way :)

```
def count_by(x, y)
  y.times.with_object([]) do |i, result|
    result << x*(i+1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-c-new) can be used here.

```
def count_by(x, n)
  Array.new(n) { |i| x*(i+1) }
end

count_by(1,5)   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
count_by(2,5)   #=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
count_by(3,5)   #=> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
count_by(50,5)  #=> [50, 100, 150, 200, 250]
count_by(100,5) #=> [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
count_by(0,5)   #=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few other ways to achieve the same result. Using [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step):

```
x.step(by: x, to: x*y).entries
```

shorter but less readable:

```
x.step(x*y, x).entries
```

or using a range with [`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
(x..x*y).step(x).entries
```

In each of the examples `entries` can be replaced with `to_a`